# Starting python Klein using twistd throws no module Error

Tags: python, twisted, twistd, klein-mvc

- Hi, I am trying to start a Klein server using `twistd` method. I
  tried it by reading the Klein [documentation](https://media.readthedocs.org/pdf/klein/latest/klein.pdf).
- But when I tried to start the server, it says no module found.

Here is the sample code of what i tried,

**helloworld.py :**

```
from klein import Klein
from klein import resource, route
app = Klein()

@route('/')
def hello(request):
    return "Hello, world!"
```

Then I run the following command:

```
twistd -n web --class=helloworld.resource
```

I got the following error :

```
File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\twisted\python\reflect.py", line 165, in namedObject
    module = namedModule('.'.join(classSplit[:-1]))
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\twisted\python\reflect.py", line 151, in namedModule
    topLevel = __import__(name)
ImportError: No module named helloworld
```

Answer (score 1):

Put the directory containing your `helloworld.py` into the import path.  For example, add it to `PYTHONPATH`:

```
$ PYTHONPATH=${PWD} twistd -n web --class=helloworld.resource
```

Comment: thx,  in my case PYTHONPATH=${PWD} must be on the executed line. setting PYTHONPATH independently wasn't sufficient.

Comment: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/368944/what-is-the-difference-between-env-setenv-export-and-when-to-use