# Run GUI concurrently with Flask application

Tags: python, user-interface, flask, python-multiprocessing

I'm trying to build a simple tkinter GUI window around my flask application for noobs in my office. I want the script to perform these tasks in the following order:

- Start the flask web server
- Open a tkinter GUI window with one button. When pressed, that button opens the app's index page (e.g. http://127.0.0.1:5000)
- Terminate the flask web server when the tkinter gui window is closed

This is what I have so far but the app runs independently of the tkinter window and I must terminate the flask app using crtl+c before I even see the gui window:

```
from flask_app import app
from tkinter import tk
import webbrowser

class GUI:
    def __init__(self):
        app.run()
        self.btn = tk.Button(root, text='Open in Browser', command:self.open_browser_tab).pack()

    def open_browser_tab(self):
        webbrowser.open(url='http:127.0.0.1:5000', new=2)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    root = tk.Tk()
    GUI(root)
    root.mainloop()
```

So how can I run a process while the app's running?

Comment: http://127.0.0.1:5000 is no good if you want it for other computers, that will be only available on your computer.

Comment: Correct, I only want it available on the computer running it.

Comment: use threading, invoke GUI with Threads

Comment: Go for `subprocess` or `os`.  Threading is not safe, plus it's confusing to read.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

### Options

The flask application is blocking your GUI.  You have two options:

1. threading/multithreading
2. separate applications

### Multiple Threads

It is possible to write `tkinter` applications with multiple threads, but you must take care to do it.

- `tkinter` must be run within the primary thread
- `tkinter` cannot be accessed or implemented from any thread other than the primary

### Separate Processes

I would recommend using the [`subprocess`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/subprocess.html) module.  If you separate our your functionality into two applications and use the subprocess module to start/stop the flask application, I think you will have what you want.

Comment: It's not unsafe to use multiple threads, as long as all tkinter code runs in the same thread.

Comment: Ok, good deal.  Also worth noting that tkinter has to run in the primary thread.  I see that I didn't mention that.  Will modify answer.

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest taking a look at the [Klein web micro-framework](https://github.com/twisted/klein) which runs on Twisted Python. It's similar to Flask and may suit your needs and will allow you to run it all in a single process.

You can integrate it with the event loop of various UI toolkits, including [tkinter](http://twistedmatrix.com/documents/13.2.0/core/howto/choosing-reactor.html#auto16).

Comment: thx, if finally worked as expected. And if like me you struggle ton run twistd using the example from the klein documentation that might be because of this : https://stackoverflow.com/a/41446946/5075502