# Tkinter not responding when i run Flask

Tags: python, flask, tkinter

"Tkinter window not responding after i clicked a button widget with the command of running Flask code that display a simple "Hello world" on http://127.0.0.1:5001" with webbrowser."

> This is the Tkinter script:

```
from tkinter import * 
from test import flask_open

def f1():
    flask_open()

root = Tk()

button_click = Button(root, command=f1, text="Button") 
button_click.pack()

root.mainloop()
```

> This is the Flask script:

```
from flask import Flask
import webbrowser

class flask_open:
    def __init__(self):
        app = Flask(__name__)

        @app.route("/")
        def hello():
            return "Hello World!"

        webbrowser.open("http://127.0.0.1:5001")
        app.run(port=5001)
```

Comment: `app.run()` is blocking the gui thread. For ideas see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47169221/run-gui-concurrently-with-flask-application).

Comment: Thanks for your advice. After taking your advice, i able to solve it with this http://sebastiandahlgren.se/2014/06/27/running-a-method-as-a-background-thread-in-python/