# Tkinter and Flask integration not working after compiling

Tags: python, user-interface, flask, python-multiprocessing

I have a small web app designed for Flask that is designed to run locally. I used Flask because I prefer to use a web browser for the GUI even though this is a local app. I want to share this app with my coworkers, so I used pyinstaller to create an executable. This works perfectly, but terminating the process is required to stop Flask. I was hoping to do this more gracefully, and I found this:

[Run GUI concurrently with Flask application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47169221/run-gui-concurrently-with-flask-application)

This sounds exactly like what I'm trying to do. After some experimenting, I finally got everything working. Launching the app opens a tkinter window. The user can either Start or Stop the Flask app with the Buttons presented. Starting the Flask app opens the default web browser to the correct page. The Flask app is started as a new process with the tkinter window being the parent/daemon. Closing the tkinter window or pressing the Stop button terminates the Flask server. Everything works as expected in my development environment, but not when I compile it for Windows with pyinstaller.

As a .exe file, the tkinter window opens, but the Flask server is not started. When the Start button is pressed, the web page opens but a standard "site not found" message is displayed. Then, my tkinter window duplicates itself so there are two windows displayed. If I edit my code to start the Flask server immediately and bypass opening the tkinter window, everything works again.

Below is the layout of my app:

```
|   run.py
+---my_flask_app
|   |   forms.py
|   |   routes.py
|   |   __init__.py
|   |   
|   +---static
|   |   +---css
|   |   +---img
|   |   \---js
|   |           
|   +---templates
```

I'll just post the code where Flask is being started from tkinter in run.py unless more is needed:

```
def start(self):
        global p #global so can be accessed in stop function.
        p = Process(target=startFlask,)
        p.daemon=True
        p.start()            
        webbrowser.open(url='http:127.0.0.1:5000', new=2)

def startFlask():
        app.run()
```

The pyinstaller commandline is:

```
pyinstaller  -F --add-data "my_flask_app;my_flask_app" --onefile run.py
```

I've tried a few variations of this will no luck. In summary, I can start the Flask app from a .exe as long as I don't involve the tkinter GUI. Also, I can start the Flask app from the tkinkter GUI in my development environment, but this breaks as described when I compile to a .exe.

Answer (score 0):

The answer to this problem is to use "freeze_support()". Apparently, this is required when converting a python app using multiprocessing to a Windows executable. I don't exactly understand why, but I'm glad everything is working now!

https://docs.python.org/3/library/multiprocessing.html#multiprocessing.freeze_support